# Why can we bounty a question in a value that is higher that what we own?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounties

When we bounty a question, shouldn't the bounty value be no more that what we have?

[image]

in this example, how nCdy can bounty a **150 points** is he/she only have 2?

> [from Stackoverflow question **3455570**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455570/treeview-selected-node-style-doesnt-appears-to-selected-node)

Comment: you should feel sorry for this user, they sacrificed *all* their rep to get an answer!

Comment: or, don't really care about it, like we normally do, I'm guessing is to ZEN... way above SO Trilogy, eheheh :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rep is deducted when the bounty is started. Therefore [@nCdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238232/ncdy) had ~152 rep before starting the bounty, as you can see from the [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238232?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top).

Don't worry, the cheques will clear :)

Comment: forgot all about to check the graph ... I thought that was "collected" only when the the time got to zero :-( my bad!

Answer (score 2):

Actually he had 152 reputation points right before he posted the bounty. Since the bounty is immediately deducted when set, he is now down to a rep of 2. Actually he had more than 152 so I assume this is not his first bounty question.

I would imagine he is really desperate to get an answer or doesn't care about rep at all. You can view his reputation graph on his profile to see how this happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238232?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top).

Comment: got it, thxs ... my bad :(